# Can I change a custom post type label from a child theme?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm developing a child theme of a premium template, this comes with a custom post type with the label name of "Projects" but I'd like to change it to something else, I know that if I go to the functions.php file of the main theme I can change it easily but I'd like to change it from my child theme so I don't have to edit any of the original files, is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a global array `$wp_post_types`. You can change `$wp_post_types[$post_type]->labels` after the parent theme has set the CPT.

So … if the parent theme registers the CPT on `'init'` like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_cpt', 12 );
```

Then you need a later priority:

```
add_action( 'init', 'change_cpt_labels', 13 );
```

… or a later hook. I would use `wp_loaded`:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'change_cpt_labels' );
```

### Example for custom post type `place` changed to `location`

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_19240_change_place_labels', 20 );

function wpse_19240_change_place_labels()
{
    $p_object = get_post_type_object( 'place' );

    if ( ! $p_object )
        return FALSE;

    // see get_post_type_labels()
    $p_object->labels->name               = 'Locations';
    $p_object->labels->singular_name      = 'Location';
    $p_object->labels->add_new            = 'Add location';
    $p_object->labels->add_new_item       = 'Add new location';
    $p_object->labels->all_items          = 'All locations';
    $p_object->labels->edit_item          = 'Edit location';
    $p_object->labels->name_admin_bar     = 'Location';
    $p_object->labels->menu_name          = 'Location';
    $p_object->labels->new_item           = 'New location';
    $p_object->labels->not_found          = 'No locations found';
    $p_object->labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No locations found in trash';
    $p_object->labels->search_items       = 'Search locations';
    $p_object->labels->view_item          = 'View location';

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: you beat me to it toscho. btw how do you pronounce your username.

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx I asked Google to make an audio file for me, and [here you go](http://translate.google.com/#de|en|toscho).

Comment: That is what i thought it would be.

Comment: @toscho would you mind expanding on this a little more? I'm not very savvy with PHP, and I'm confused as to how you would do this. Might you give an example? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JeremyMiller See my update.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar with post type args (i.e. add them after registering the post type? I'm trying to register a theme's custom post type with WP REST API via a child theme.

Comment: @raddevon You can also use `registered_post_type`. See this example: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97530/73

Comment: maybe better to use `get_post_type_object` instead of directly accessing the global

Comment: @MarkKaplun True. Done. :)