# Rewrite post type slug only for child theme

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug, child-theme

I'm in multisite where some blogs share the same parent theme for maintenance reasons. All my cpts come from that parent theme, but I would really like that, for one of the blogs, it had an URL mask.

I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19244/7890) very useful to change labels, but I've tried to do the same and assign a different slug to `$wp_post_types[$post_type]->rewrite['slug']` and it fails, bringing the whole rewrite array to NULL.

I've also tried .htacces with `RewriteRule ^/newslug$ /oldslug [L]` but with no success.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make the [slug translatable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65680/internationalize-translate-custom-post-types-taxonomies/65951#65951) when you register the custom post type:

```
register_post_type( 
    'post_type_name', 
    array (
        'rewrite' => array (
            'slug' => _x( 'post_type_name', 'URL slug', 'your_text_domain' )
        )
    )
);
```

Then create a small plugin for the site where you want to change the slug:

```
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'change_my_slug', 10, 4 );

function change_my_slug( $translation, $text, $context, $domain )
{
    if ( 'URL slug' !== $context or 'post_type_name' !== $text or 'your_text_domain' !== $domain )
        return $translation;

    return 'changed-slug';
}
```