# Change labels of custom post type via child theme

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme

I have a WordPress parent theme that uses a custom post type called `portfolio`, which I'd like to change to `property`.

I'd like to have all of the contextual elements changed to show `property` like, `"show properties"`, `"add new property"`, `"delete property"`, etc.
I know I can do this by updating the parent theme, but I'd prefer not to, if I can avoid it.

I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19240/can-i-change-a-custom-post-type-label-from-a-child-theme), but unfortunately, I'm not PHP savvy enough to write my own function and change this.

Can someone help me out with this? I'm kind of stuck.
I have a feeling this is something simple for a PHP Dev. I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$wp_post_types` is a global array that holds `post_type` objects, which in turn have a `labels` property.
You can change `$wp_post_types[$post_type]->labels` after the parent theme has set the CPT.

Add higher priority to `init` hook.

Add the following code in your theme's `functions.php` file.

For more information, check out [the codex article on `get_post_type_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object).

```
function change_post_object_label() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $labels = &$wp_post_types['portfolio']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Property';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Property';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Property';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Property';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Property';
    $labels->new_item = 'Property';
    $labels->all_items = 'All Properties';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Property';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Property';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Property found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Property found in Trash';    
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_post_object_label', 999 );
```

Add following code in `functions.php` to replace main menu label from sidebar

```
function change_post_menu_label() {
  global $menu;
  //print_r($menu); Print menus and find out the index of your custom post type menu from it.
  $menu[27][0] = 'Bacons'; // Replace the 27 with your custom post type menu index from displayed above $menu array 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_post_menu_label' );
```

Add following code in `functions.php` for adding image to admin sidebar CPT menu

```
add_action('admin_head', 'change_CPT_icon');
function change_CPT_icon() {?>
  <style>
    #menu-posts-portfolio .wp-menu-image { background: url('<?php echo  get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/includes/images/new-image.png';?>') no-repeat 5px 5px transparent !important; }     
  </style>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems to work, with one exception. The main label on the sidebar is not changing. It looks like "name" should be changing that. Any ideas?

Comment: Vinod, I'm curious if it's this simple to change the arguments for the custom post type. I'm trying to change the image used in the menu. I've got: `$args = &$wp_post_types['portfolio']->args; 
 $args->menu_icon = get_template_directory_uri() .'/includes/images/new-image.png';` but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I have added the code in answer  to change the image used in the menu.

Comment: Hi Vinod, I'm not sure that will work. That's changing the background of the div, where the current function adds the actual image. So this would change the background, but the original image would still show up. Thoughts?

Comment: @JeremyMiller It will overwrite the original image.

Answer (score 0):

This changes the labels and the menu name. Also a bonus to change the slug too.

This example changes a registered post type called 'services' to 'specialty' (American English spelling).

**Change the labels and the name all at once:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'yourprefix_change_cpt_service_to_specialty_labels' );
/**
 * Change Post Type Post Labels to Blog
 * Reference(s):
 * https://wpbeaches.com/change-the-wordpress-post-type-name-to-something-else/
 * https://revelationconcept.com/wordpress-rename-default-posts-news-something-else/
 */
function yourprefix_change_cpt_service_to_specialty_labels() {

    if ( post_type_exists( 'services' ) ) :

        $get_post_type = get_post_type_object('services');
        $labels = $get_post_type->labels;
        $labels->name               = 'Specialty';
        $labels->singular_name      = 'Specialty Page';
        $labels->add_new            = 'Add Specialty Page';
        $labels->add_new_item       = 'Add Specialty Page';
        $labels->edit_item          = 'Edit Specialty Page';
        $labels->new_item           = 'New Specialty Page';
        $labels->view_item          = 'View Specialty Page';
        $labels->search_items       = 'Search Specialty Pages';
        $labels->not_found          = 'No Specialties found';
        $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Specialty Pages found in Trash';
        $labels->all_items          = 'All Specialty Pages';
        $labels->menu_name          = 'Specialties';
        $labels->name_admin_bar     = 'Specialty Page';

    endif;
}
```

**Bonus: Change the slug. Don't forget to save your permalinks after this is added.**

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'yourprefix_change_post_types_slug_service', 10, 2 );
// Change Slug of Registered Post Type for Services // Resave your PERMALINKS or this will return 404!!!
function yourprefix_change_post_types_slug_service( $args, $post_type ) {

   /*item post type slug*/   
   if ( 'services' === $post_type ) :
      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'specialty';
   endif;

   return $args;
}
```