# CPT Template Not Showing - Getting 404

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, debug, template-hierarchy

I'm developing a Custom Post Type plugin, which works fine in dev. Now that I've moved it to production, I'm getting a 404 when I try to display the template for the CPT.

So, two questions:

1- Is there some mechanism to determine the path WP took to get through the hierarchy?

2- Why wouldn't it just give me the single or index page?

I've dumped $wp_query and a stacktrace at the end of the 404. Here's part of what I found:

```
[query] => Array
    (
        [page] => 
        [pagename] => refletters/proximity
    )

[request] => SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_posts.ID = '0') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
[posts] => Array
    (
    )

[queried_object] => 
[queried_object_id] => 0
```

And the stack trace:

```
2013-04-27 22:16:41 - 24.52.197.40 - TRACE - index.php - 404.php[39] - 
    wordpress/wp-content/themes/notoriousconsultant/404.php[39] - aaLog->logtrace
    wordpress/wp-includes/template-loader.php[50] - include
    wordpress/wp-blog-header.php[16] - require_once
    wordpress/index.php[17] - require
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Always flush the rewrite rules when you register a new public post type or taxonomy. Otherwise the internal rewrite rules will not take that into account when an URL is mapped to a query.

You can automate that process by hooking into `registered_post_type` and `registered_taxonomy`.

Below is the updated code, based on feedback from comments and other people.

Download as plugin [T5 Silent Flush](https://gist.github.com/toscho/5477050) on GitHub.

```
add_action( 'registered_post_type', 't5_silent_flush_cpt', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'registered_taxonomy',  't5_silent_flush_tax', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Flush rules for custom post types.
 *
 * @wp-hook registered_post_type
 * @param   string $post_type
 * @param   stdClass $args
 * @return  void
 */
function t5_silent_flush_cpt( $post_type, $args )
{
    if ( $args->_builtin )
        return;

    if ( ! $args->public )
        return;

    if ( ! $args->publicly_queryable )
        return;

    if ( ! $args->rewrite )
        return;

    $slug = $post_type;

    if ( isset ( $args->rewrite['slug'] ) && is_string( $args->rewrite['slug'] ) )
        $slug = $args->rewrite['slug'];

    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset ( $rules[ $slug . '/?$'] ) )
        flush_rewrite_rules( FALSE );
}

/**
 * Flush rules for custom post taxonomies.
 *
 * @wp-hook registered_taxonomy
 * @param   string $taxonomy
 * @param   string $object_type
 * @param   array  $args
 * @return  void
 */
function t5_silent_flush_tax( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args )
{
    // No idea why we get an array here, but an object for post types.
    // Objects are easier to write, so ...
    $args = (object) $args;

    if ( $args->_builtin )
        return;

    if ( ! $args->public )
        return;

    if ( ! $args->rewrite )
        return;

    $slug = $taxonomy;

    if ( isset ( $args->rewrite['slug'] ) && is_string( $args->rewrite['slug'] ) )
        $slug = $args->rewrite['slug'];


    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset ( $rules[ $slug . '/(.+?)/?$'] ) )
        flush_rewrite_rules( FALSE );
}
```

This will flush the rules each time you create a new post type or taxonomy. No need to visit the permalink settings again.

Comment: I'm thinking of adding this to the CPT plugin itself. Doesn't seem to make sense to require a user to have another plugin for my plugin to work.

Comment: Yes, of course. I just wanted to provide a reusable example for other readers with the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like this should be in core

Comment: Had a few questions on this: will this be as resource intensive as flushing the rewrite rules and does this run every time WP loads?

Comment: @MannyFleurmond Yes, it will run each time the post type is registered. But the rules are only flushed when necessary, and the `get_option()` value comes from the cache.

Comment: @toscho Nice.  Will this flush all rewrite rules or just those of that post type?  will this effect those created by `add_rewrite_rule`?  BTW love getting these little nuggets of knowledge like this)

Comment: @MannyFleurmond It runs on `registered_post_type` only, not on other rewrite rules. And it will flush all rules, see the core code for [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L106).

Comment: Last question(I hope): Will this work for someone with a more customized permalink set for their CPT?

Comment: Depends on the `slug` parameter. Test it.