# Custom post type URL returns 404 error page

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms

I have a post_type called "products" and inside it have two taxonomies "destinations" and "types".

Inside destinations i have a list of countries as terms and inside types i have (hotels, cruises).

I want to get hotels of a particular country like this :

http://www.mydomaine.com/products/?destinations=alabama&types=hotels

Normaly wordpress should list me hotels in Alabama, not?

But for the reason i don't know it gets me 404 error page (always return back go home page).

Somebody knows why?

I have template strucutre like this :

index.php
taxonomy.php
taxonomy-destinations.php
taxonomy-types-cruise.php
taxonomy-types-hotels.php

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you seen [CPT Template Not Showing - Getting 404](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/97525/73)?

Comment: I deactivated permalinks and following query not works anymore :


http://www.mydomaine.com/products?destinations=alabama&types=hotels

or

http://www.mydomaine.com/?destinations=alabama&types=hotels