# Why do all my custom post types return a 404, even after resetting the permalink?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, 404-error

I have two custom post types setup like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_News' );
function create_post_type_News() {
    register_post_type( 'news',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'News' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 
            'editor', 
            'author', 
            'thumbnail'
        )
        )
    );
}
```

when I try to view the page (`/%postname%/` is used as permalink) I get the standard 404 message "Not Found Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found. Perhaps searching will help."

I've tried the standard fix:

- set permalink back to default and save
- set permalink back to desired style and save

The page **will** show with permalinks as default but not customized.

Comment: I have checked your code (Copied and reset permalink) and have found no problem with it. It's creating posts called news and displaying full posts.

URL where to search this post is: SITENAME/news/POST_SLUG

Comment: I've actually just followed this step by step and still have the issue: [How to Fix WordPress Custom Post Type Permalink 404 Error](http://dreamdare.org/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-wordpress-custom-post-type-permalink-404-error/)

Comment: Enable the rewrite module on your server.

Comment: according to hostgator to have rewrite on I just need a .htaccess file and turn it on through there. I've done this already. The permalinks work for everything but my custom post types (I have two)

Comment: Have you tried [Silent Flush](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97530/73)?

Comment: @toscho - this seemed to have fixed it. can you post this as an answer so I can mark it? I want to be sure you get the credit.

Comment: @dcp3450 I don’t make my rep with duplicates. :) Good to read that you could fix it.