# Custom Post Type causes Page Not Found

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, post-type

I found a basic tutorial online which gave the rundown on how to create a plugin from scratch and sets up a new custom post type. I could not find any basic coupon plugins that accomplished what I wanted, why I decided to look into creating one myself.

Unfortunately after completing the tutorial, I came to the part where I actually view the page, only to be greeted with a "Page Not Found" despite publishing my post. Can anyone check this out and let me know exactly what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php

/**
* Plugin Name: Coupons
* Plugin URI: http://coupon.net
* Description: A coupon system plugin
* Version: 1.0.0
* Author: Brett Powell
* Author URI: http://coupon.net
**/

// Register the Custom Post Type "Coupon"
function register_cpt_coupon()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Coupons', 'coupon' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Coupon', 'coupon' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'coupon' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Coupon', 'coupon' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Coupon', 'coupon' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Coupon', 'coupon' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Coupon', 'coupon' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Coupons', 'coupon' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No coupons found', 'coupon' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No coupons found in Trash', 'coupon' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Coupon:', 'coupon' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Coupons', 'coupon' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Coupons filterable by company',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'genres' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-audio',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'coupon', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_coupon' );

// Create Genre Taxonomy type
function genres_taxonomy()
{
    register_taxonomy(
        'genres',
        'coupon',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Genres',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'genre',
                'with_front' => false
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'genres_taxonomy');

// Function used to automatically create Coupon page.
function create_coupon_pages()
{
   //post status and options
    $post = array(
          'comment_status' => 'open',
          'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
          'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'post_name' => 'coupon',
          'post_status' => 'publish' ,
          'post_title' => 'Coupons',
          'post_type' => 'page',
    );
    //insert page and save the id
    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );

    //save the id in the database
    update_option( 'couponpage', $newvalue );
}

// // Activates function if plugin is activated
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_coupon_pages');

?>
```

Comment: Have you seen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97525/cpt-template-not-showing-getting-404?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You quite likely need to simply visit your permalink settings page to refresh.  Goto Admin  >  Settings  > Permalinks.  Then try your URL on the front-end again.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot believe it was that simple but that was indeed the answer. Only problem with Wordpress, there is literally too much information available sometimes. Can you share why exactly this is necessary?

Comment: Glad that solved it for you.  Sorry, but I cannot explain exactly why this is necessary.  I wish I could but I do not have enough understanding of how WP is creating the rewrite rules in the first place.  There are certainly other members of this community that do have that knowledge.