# Change slug of registered custom post type in child theme

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, child-theme, slug

I successfully renamed a custom post type registered by my parent theme in my child theme using [this method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19240/can-i-change-a-custom-post-type-label-from-a-child-theme#answer-19244). The problem is, my permalinks haven't changed. So when I change `portfolio` to `homepage` and use the permalink structure `/%category%/%postname%/` my URLs still look like mysite.com/**portfolio**/page/ instead of mysite.com/**homepage**/page/.

this is the code I am using to change my CPT:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_19240_change_home_labels', 20 );

function wpse_19240_change_home_labels()
{
global $wp_post_types;
$b = 'portfolio';

if ( empty ( $wp_post_types[ $b ] )
    or ! is_object( $wp_post_types[ $b ] )
    or empty ( $wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels )
    )
    return;

$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->name               = 'Sliders';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->singular_name      = 'Slider';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->add_new_item       = 'Add New Slider';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->edit_item          = 'Edit Slider';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->new_item           = 'New Slider';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->view_item          = 'View Slider';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->search_items       = 'Search Sliders';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->not_found          = 'No sliders found.';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No sliders found in Trash.';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->menu_name          = 'Homepage Sliders';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->all_items          = 'All Sliders';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->add_new            = 'Add New Slider';
$wp_post_types[ $b ]->labels->name_admin_bar     = 'Slider';
}
```

I sucessfully changed the slug by using:

```
function change_slug_of_post_type_portfolio() {
    register_post_type('portfolio', array('rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'homepage',)));
}
add_action('init', 'change_slug_of_post_type_portfolio', 20);
```

But now I get a 404 error when I navigate to the page generated by the system: mysite.com/homepage/page/

I made sure to make a single-homepage.php and I have tried adding `flush_rewrite_rules();` as recommended in [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalink-to-custom-post-type-gives-me-404-error?replies=14) but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with your code you completely redefine your CPT instead of just modifying the slug
maybe this change the public access

try this :

```
$args = get_post_type_object("portfolio");
$args->rewrite["slug"] = "homepage";
register_post_type($args->name, $args);
```

Comment: I tried adding that to both functions and still got a 404 :(

Comment: have you flush the rewrite rules before to test ? just go to the permalink admin page and save

Comment: That worked! Added flush_rewrite_rules(); before my second function. Quick question. If I plan to do this several times will I need to flush the rewrite rules every time?

Comment: you need to flush everytime you modify the rules in order to put the new rules in WP cache. but it take long time to flush so don't make it at every page load